# Placing inner divs in row

Tags: html, css

I have a div container which contains 3 different divs. I want to place inner divs in a row.
Here is html code:
[This is what it should look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cY1zP.png)

```css
.partners {
  display: inline-block;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="partners">
  <div>
    <img src="media/handshake.png" alt="handshake" class="handshake">
    <h1>10+</h1>
    <p>partners investing their time and effort to support our mission</p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <img src="media/social-care.png" alt="social care" class="social-care">
    <h1>150+</h1>
    <p>members working hard to be able to support our mission</p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <img src="media/respect.png" alt="respect" class="respect">
    <h1>243+</h1>
    <p>donors supporting our community and making impossible possible</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

But the last inner div goes beyond the screen and when I inspect the page it shows that "partners" div contains only first and second inner divs.

How can I solve this?
[This is what it looks like when I inspect.The third one is not included in "partners" div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wsuQ.png)

Comment: It seems to work fine ?

Comment: you are using `display` 2 times. Just choose if you want `flex` or `inline-block`

Comment: looks good to me. Can you share a screenshot of the inspector? Also, as @OmriAttiya mentioned, make sure you use `display` once. `flex` should work fine.

Comment: I deleted display: inline-block but it didn't solve the problem. Only change is that now inspector contains 2 divs.

Answer (score 0):

This often happen if you forget to close a tag in html. 
Please check the rest of your code to be sure you didn't forget to close any tag. You also can use online unclosed html tags checker like this one :

https://www.aliciaramirez.com/closing-tags-checker/

Comment: I checked it and my html code doesn't contain any unchecked tags.

Comment: Thank you for this website, it will be useful for me in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to use something like metroui or even bootstrap ?

I.E.: 
With metroUI you can use the grid system to do exactly what you want, see : 
https://metroui.org.ua/grid.html#_media_columns

Here is a link explaining how to include metroui in your project :

https://metroui.org.ua/intro.html#_quick_start

Answer (score 0):

This will fix your problem.

```
.partners{
    justify-content:space-around;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}

.partners div{
    width:30%;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

ypu can set up a max width to the children divs, using like `.partners div { width: 30% }` and to add some space between them, you can also use `.partners { justify-content: space-between; }` tip: display inline-block is canceled when you put another display: flex above, try use only flex

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I tried your solution, but it only affects images and h1s. These two are placed nicely, however paragraphs below them are on the right side of each image and h1 and I still have expanded window. Can you please help me to solve this problem?